# How to find scope of React function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, typeerror

I am trying to call a React hook function dynamically like this:

```
const Selector = () => {
    const [year, setYear] = useState("2020")

    function handleSelection(variable, e) {
        console.log(variable, e.target.value)
        // trying to call function below with 'window' as the scope
        window["set" + variable.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + variable.slice(1)](e.target.value)
    }
```

I've tried `window` and `Selector` till now. But it shows

```
TypeError: window[("set" + variable.charAt(...).toUpperCase(...) + variable.slice(...))] is not a function
```

But when I console log `"set" + variable.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + variable.slice(1)` it shows me the name of my React hook function i.e. setYear, setMonth, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `local` equivalent to `window` (and you shouldn't really rely on accessing globals via `window` anyway!).

You'll want something like

```
const Selector = () => {
    const [year, setYear] = useState("2020");
    const [month, setMonth] = useState("10");
    const setters = {year: setYear, month: setMonth};
    function handleSelection(variable, e) {
        // assumes `variable` is `year` or `month`
        setters[variable](e.target.value);
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks this is much cleaner for me. Could you please explain why I shouldn't use window for accessing globals?

Comment: Globals in general can make it harder to test things. But in the presence of bundlers and multiple modules, there's no guarantee that what you think is a "top-level" variables is actually assigned into `window` at all.

Comment: As an aside, how would you imagine something using globals could work if you had multiple `<Selector />` components on a page?